# Upload File from modal popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a modal popup, inserting new records on a database table. All the records inserted successfully except the upload file. Neither the filename inserted on the database table neither the file uploaded on folder. When I run my code on the page not from the modal popup the code works. I am working on localhost.
My code:

```
string myfileuploadpath; if (myAttachedFile.FileName != "")
            {
                fileuploadpath = "~\\myFiles\\" + myAttachedFile.FileName;
                string myPath = Server.MapPath(myfileuploadpath);
                myAttachedFile.SaveAs(myPath);
                myitem.AttachedFiles = myfileuploadpath;
            }
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" Visible="false" runat="server">
                     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                     <ContentTemplate>
<asp:FileUpload ID="myAttachedFile" runat="server" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Comment: check this link http://rrmtricks.blogspot.in/2012/08/aspnet-classic-fileupload-control-using.html

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that i had an update panel inside the place holder. When i removed it the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can't upload a file via AJAX, which is what I suspect you're doing in your modal popup. The only ways to upload a file is by posting the form back to the server normally (remember to set multi-part/formdata), or using a Flash/SilverLight app.